# FindControl results in null reference

Tags: asp.net

I have anchor tags like this

```
 <div id="menu_container">
            <ul id="nav-bar">
                <li><a href="Default.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_item_default">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Account.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_item_account" >Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="Servers.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_item_servers">Servers</a></li>
                <li><a href="Statistics.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_item_statistics">Statistics</a></li>
                <li><a href="Tutorials.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_item_tutorials">Tutorials</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.aspx" runat="server" id="menu_item_contact">Contact us</a></li>
                <div id="login_registration_container">
                    <a href="#" id="login">Sign in</a> / <a href="Registration.aspx" id="register">Register</a>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I want to change the CSS class for `menu_item_default` this way:

```
WebControl wc = (WebControl)FindControl("#menu_item_default");
wc.Attributes.Add("class", "value");
```

> error: null reference exception

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using a MasterPage and the element is in a ContentPlaceholder:**

If so then you must retrieve the ContentPlaceholder first, and from it retrive the element you want.

If your page has the following Content-area for example:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
```

Then you would do the following (error handling omitted):

```
   var mainCtrl = Master.FindControl("MainContent");
   var anchor = (HtmlAnchor) mainCtrl.FindControl("menu_item_default");
   anchor.Attributes.Add("class", "value");
```

**Using a MasterPage and the element is in the MasterPage:**

use:

```
   var anchor = (HtmlAnchor) Master.FindControl("menu_item_default");
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use '#' symbol in the FindControl argument:

```
WebControl wc = (WebControl)FindControl("menu_item_default");
```

Comment: @Acid Is this control inside the form ? Then maybe its find it but its not WebControl, look to see if find it as object, then what it is

Comment: no this anchor tags are inside the master page ... My web form cannot access them?

Comment: @Acid, if the controls are inside a master page then use master's `FindControl` method `this.Master.FindControl(...)` instead. `FindControl` looks in the current naming container only.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote this and and asp found control Control ctrl = this.Master.FindControl("menu_item_default"); but how i can change ctrl s css class?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you are using a regular anchor tag?  Why not use an ASP.Net LinkButton?  That will make it much easier to reference in the code.

If the control is on the master page, try
    Master.FindControl()

Comment: He can reference any control with runat=server on the server-side.

Comment: I know, but there are more options when dealing with an actual .Net control.